# Add extra fields to register form woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I've followed the following [link](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page) which allows data to be saved via a field name i.e. billing_city, billing_phone which is great and helps me a little.

Although their is a requirement to add extra information such as Representative account number.

I've added the following code to within my form-login.php

```
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="rep_account_number"><?php _e( 'Rep account number', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="rep_account_number" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['rep_account_number'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['rep_account_number'] ); ?>" />
                </p>
```

Now where I'm stuck is how to get the above information to save to an individual person's account. I've found wp_usermeta table which has some of the standard field names such as reg_billing_phone etc. I can't figure it out.

Help appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: [Customizing WooCommerce Checkout Fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/517/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've tried to modify her code to get it to work for my needs, i.e. assigning it to customer_id instead of order_id however I cannot get it to work. Could you look at my code? [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJgVQM.html)